# Errore in read_osm(dat, ext = 1.1) : No internet connection found

Tags: r

> Error in read_osm(dat, ext = 1.1) : No internet connection found.

How can I solve it?? thank you

I did control internet connection and crs data, but i can't solve the error.
I've the packages:

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(OpenStreetMap)
```

I dont know what is the problem, I should create a base map

Comment: The error message comes from `tmaptols::read_osm()` function: https://github.com/r-tmap/tmaptools/blob/0c8b0b1c68bb20c7561715011812ca39e2085132/R/read_osm.R#L20 which checks what's the status of environment variable `!get(".internet", envir = .TMAPTOOLS_CACHE)`. This variable is set up while the package is loaded: line 3 and 10th in onLoad.R file. In short, it's checking if `working_internet <- function(url = "http://www.google.com")` the connection to google works. Try to restart R session or make sure the connection works.